# dijit.Calendar default value

Tags: xpages, dojo

I am trying to set the current date in a `dijit.Calendar` but for some reason it is not setting, and I'm not getting any errors either. I am also trying to get the value selected to populate a field or session scope variable but this is not happening either - simply get a `dom.byId()` is null error.

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Calendar" id="myCal">
<script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onLoad" data-dojo-args="value">
                require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/date/locale"],
                function(dom, locale){
                dom.byId('myCal').set('value',new Date());});

</script>
<script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onChange"
                    data-dojo-args="value">
                    require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/date/locale"],
                    function(dom, locale){
                    dom.byId('formatted').innerHTML =
                    locale.format(value, {formatLength: 'medium',
                    selector:'date'}); });
</script>
</div>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't look like an Xpages problem at all; I'll remove that Tag for you. In case I'm wrong please add info in what aspect your problem is Xpages-related

Comment: The calendar sits in an xPage and I am trying to set the value when it loads. I then want to select a date and have it populate a field on my xPage. In the code above I can populate an HTML element with the date, but it fails when I try to do the same to a field.

Comment: So I was mistaken by the code which doesn't show anything related to Xpages code whatsoever; sorry for that. Can you show some more code examples indicating how you tried to communicate with Xpages controls and/or Notes fields? Maybe then we get an idea what you're trying to achieve and where you're failing

Comment: Let me get this right you need a calendar where you can pick a date and which has the current date as default value and you want to set a session scope war with it? why dont you use a simple date input field wich has a dojo dateselection out of the box? Also what Notes Version are you using? This Looks like dojo 1.9 but for example notes 8.5.3 comes with dojo 1.6

Comment: Hi -  That is exactly what I am trying to achieve Michael. I am Using Domino 9.01 and dojo 1.83. I have the calendar widget which when clicked will return the date value and then show the calendar page for that date. I don't want to use a date input field as it looks naff. I will post more of my code later on as I have a meeting to go to....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also using a Calendar widget in one of my applications in notes 8.5.3 dojo 1.6. so it may not work in your xpage but you could give it a try. Here what i worked out:

First don't forget to set `dojoForm="true",` `dojoParseOnLoad="true",` `dojoTheme="true".`
Then import the resources you need for the widget (i used a customized calendar.css):

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.widget.Calendar"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/calendar.css"></xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Then the difficult part i construct the widget with a JavaScriptBlock where i also set the start date (`value: new Date`) and hide a `xp:inputText` inside it wich is bound to a sessionScope variable. I submit this inputBox when a user clicks on a date of the calendar.

```
<xp:panel id="calendarHolder" style="width:200px">
        <xp:scriptBlock id="Calendar">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
        dojo.require("dojox.widget.Calendar");
        dojo.require("dojo.date","dijit.registry"); 
        dojo.ready(function(){      
            // create the Calendar:
            var selectedDate = null;

            var calendar_body = new dojox.widget.Calendar({
                    value: new Date(),
                    isDisabledDate:dojo.date.locale.isWeekend,
                    onValueSelected: function(date){calendarDateClicked(date);
                    }
                }, "calendar_body");


            //create Click action
            function calendarDateClicked(date){
                var d = new Date(date);
                var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
                var day = '' + d.getDate();
                var year = d.getFullYear();

                if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
                if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

                var dateString = [year,month,day].join("");         
                dojo.byId('#{id:hiddenCalWidgetSelectedDate}').value = dateString;
                XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:computedField1}",{});//Post Value to server
            }
        });
    });]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:scriptBlock>

    <div id="calendar_body">
        <xp:inputText
            id="hiddenCalWidgetSelectedDate"
            style="display:none;"
            value="#{sessionScope.selectedDate}">
            <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript://
var d = new Date(/*Today*/);
var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
var day = '' + d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year,month,day].join("");  }]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
            </xp:inputText>
        </div>
        </xp:panel>
```

Display the Selected date benethe the date Widget:

```
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" 
value="#{javascript: return 'Hallo' + sessionScope.selectedDate;}">
        </xp:text>
```

In my application the widget is a bit bigger because i used a menue to let the user chose different actions on a date so i extracted this code from my big one and tested it on an empty Xpage. Hope it helps =)

Comment: Cheers Michael - will try this first thing tomorrow morning :-)